# Find Webpage Element Using Requests, Scrapy or Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to interact with a webpage that has strong bot detection measures. This means I cannot use things like Requests, Scrapy or Selenium as they get detected. Even Undetected Chromedriver doesn't work.

I just need to perform a few simple clicks on the site so am trying to implement something using Pyautogui.

However, I still need to find whether certain elements exist. Is there a way of doing this without using those libraries?

Comment: Why has the question been closed? It is different to the ones listed.